# How do I fix error on paging using Datatables and server side data source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the datatables framework described here:

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

I'm able to get the example defined at this url to work on the initial page load.  However the sort and page buttons do not work.  When the button is pressed the ajax call seems to be called: the server returns a json string representing the data (it it the same string shown in the ajax tab).  The call seems to return the data to the page (I can see the json string in the response using Chrome tools).  However, the table does not seem to refresh and the "Processing..." window never clears.

This is what the javascript in the page looks like:

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "${home}/Forward?actionClass=serverexample.ServerExampleAction"
            } );
        } );
    </script>
</head>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

--- EDIT ------------

Also, is there a way I can debug this (e.g. add an alert to see what code is actually executing, I'm not using the minimized js, I'm using datatables.js).

The JSON returned by the query is this:

```
{
  "draw": 10,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      "Caesar",
      "Vance",
      "Pre-Sales Support",
      "New York",
      "12th Dec 11",
      "$106,450"
    ],
    [
      "Cara",
      "Stevens",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "New York",
      "6th Dec 11",
      "$145,600"
    ],
    [
      "Cedric",
      "Kelly",
      "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "29th Mar 12",
      "$433,060"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: what does the json look like? i see in the FAQ a couple comments about processing remaining on the page if response has something unexpected.

Comment: Q. It's not working... (stuck on Processing)
A. This is usually down to incorrect JSON data being passed back from the server. Please refer to this technical note on how to debug and resolve this issue.

Q. It's still not working...
A. The next most common reason for server-side processing not working is the draw variable not being returned as it was set in the request. DataTables uses draw to keep a draw count, so this is an important parameter. See server-side usage.

Comment: Thanks Dan! Do you have a link for the technical note you mentioned? I added the JSON as an edit to the original post.

Comment: i was copy pasting from here: https://datatables.net/faqs/index "Server-Side processing"

Comment: If you have not yet read it, [this page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) is the page which helped me the most. Otherwise, your JSON looks OK to me - and I assume it matches the JSON from the initial page load. Are you able to provide a [mre]?